# External device input

Tags: interface, hardware, external

I am looking into what's the best method for getting external data (custom built hardware) and to intercept and process this data (programming language / tool), the cheapest and easiest and with the least learning curve.

Background:
I am a web dev.

External device will be switches, motion detection, velocity detection
Programming language: Delphy (which I don't know)? or C# (which I know for web dev) or other?

Anyone done anything like this before? Got any advice?

Any and all information is appreciated.

D

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be to use an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/).

It's :

- cheap (~ 30$)
- easy to program
- easy to connect to your PC (it use an USB cable which emulate a serial connection)
- have a HUGE community with tons of tutorials for doing whatever you want

Here is an [example how to control a led using C#](http://www.therobotlab.co.uk/2011/control-arduino-c-sharp-usb-serial/)